# Elf binary manipulation tool on ARM

Tags: arm, elf, binary

Do you know any free tool for binary manipulation elf file on ARM, something like ERESI elfsh for Intel?

Purpose - adding instructions into existing binary elf file.

Comment: Are you interested in static modification specifically? Many tools provide dynamic / runtime modification capabilies for ARM binaries

Comment: Yes, correct. I am interested in static modification - most of issues which I fix are not easily reproducible and/or require hours of running platform (any kind of stability issues). The only way (which I am using now) is to mix preloading with instruction changes, sometimes I have luck - several debug/logging instructions which I can exchange and call some @plt function which I preload then. Of course such an approach has limited use.. I presume that static injector would have serious limitations too (or even does not exist from this reason). Thank you for your time.

Comment: By preloading do you mean using LD_PRELOAD to perform dynamic library injection?

Comment: Yes. Context is that I have closed platform where apps are "ours", middleware is closed (but luckily with symbols), lower layers of userland are closed without symbols and logging (which I managed to enable, but mostly I am doomed to already implemented routines), kernel is open. This is Android but targeted stack is aside of native Android mechanisms. This is context of current project but there are also different projects where, lets say, mapping of closed and open source differs but final goal is to reverse to fix something (or find excuses or proof leting to redirect issue).

Comment: Thank you for providing these details. Unfortunately I do not have a static binary manipulation solution for you right now, but I did find a dynamic instrumentation tool for android called [adbi](https://github.com/crmulliner/adbi) that uses library injection. It is not a static modification tool but it may make your job easier. If I find something like ERESI that has support for ARM ELF binaries I will let you know.

Comment: Also, [radare2](http://nighterse.blogspot.com/2016/07/i-have-binary-patching-and-done-lot-off.html) can be used to [patch binaries](http://radare.org/get/ncn2010.pdf) statically. I should have mentioned this earlier. Apologies. Here is a link to their github repo: https://github.com/radare/radare2

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate radare2 (did it some time a go but wont of usage objdump + hopper prevented me from move to radare).